# Remove show accordion when click on another accordion in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Visit this website: http://dev.giftsdesign.com.sg/product-list/0/0

I will expect the output like,
If I click one sidebar menu, others sidebar menus should be collapsed.

Before Click: `<ul class="sidebar-submenu" style="display: none;">`

After Click: `<ul class="sidebar-submenu show" style="display: block;">`

I think this is code for that,

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.sidebar-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.next().hasClass('show')) {
            $this.next().removeClass('show');
            $this.next().slideUp(350);
        } else {
            $this.parent().parent().find('sidebar-submenu-item .sidebar-submenu').removeClass('show');
            $this.parent().parent().find('sidebar-submenu-item .sidebar-submenu').slideUp(350);
            $this.next().toggleClass('show');
            $this.next().slideToggle(350);
        }
    });
```

How to modify to get expected output. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$('.sidebar-link').click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('.show').removeClass("show");
  $('.show').css("style","none");
  ......
  
});
```

Comment: Bro, I tried your code. But if I click another sidebar menu, still previously opened menu was not closed.

Comment: I just told you the way for removing "show" class from all the menus. since you have inline style. I edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.sidebar-link').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var $this = $(this);
      document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-link').forEach(el=> {
        el.classList.remove('show')
      });
e.classList.add('show');
            $this.parent().parent().find('sidebar-submenu-item .sidebar-submenu').removeClass('show');
            $this.parent().parent().find('sidebar-submenu-item .sidebar-submenu').slideUp(350);
            $this.next().toggleClass('show');
            $this.next().slideToggle(350);
        
    });
```